# How to disable Metal Compiler Warnings when calling newLibraryWithSource

Tags: xcode, metal

I compile metal shaders on runtime in C++ app with `id<MTLLibrary> shaderLib = [myMetalDevice newLibraryWithSource:source options:options error:&error];`.

I get a lot of similar messages in log about unused variables:

```
[Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:61:14: warning: unused variable 'myVariableName'
    float4x4 myVariableName;
```

Is there a way to suppress these warnings?
I would like to ignore messages with particular warning-type if possible.
Disabling **Metal API Validation** and **Debug executable** didn't help (even in Release).

Here are related treads I've found with no answer:

[Arkit/SceneKit on iOS 14 throws new Warning (Metal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052032/arkit-scenekit-on-ios-14-throws-new-warning-metal)

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659856

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433431-newlibrarywithsource

I'm currently using xcode 12.5 on macOS Big Sur 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling this option causes all warnings to be ignored. `MTL_IGNORE_WARNINGS, -W`

Comment: Is this env variable which will only work in development on particular machine?

Comment: @RamilKudashev could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes, as I understood MTL_IGNORE_WARNINGS is something I can set on my machine when I build and launch app. But how do I set it if I build app on some build agent and launch app on other device? Or is it something I set on runtime before shader-compilation?

Comment: I tried MTL_IGNORE_WARNINGS, -W in xcode build settings as Build Settings: User-Defined, but no success. Also found these docs: https://xcodebuildsettings.com/#category-metal-opencl